# How to check relationship existence in Yii2?

Tags: activerecord, yii2, yii2-model

I have two models User and Post. While fetching the user's data I want to also check if the user has any posts and then only return posts with the user data in response other wise only return the user's details.

When I do this `$user->posts` for the user who does not have any posts it returns null which then throws an exception.

Do we have any function to check relationship existence in Yii2 while querying the model, just like we have in Laravel?

```
$userDetails = User::has('posts')->get();
```

Comment: In both cases you need to check that `$user->posts` is not empty before accessing it. So having `has()` function or not will not change your use case moreover `has()` won't return user record if there is no posts, same can be done using [innerJoinWith()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#innerJoinWith()-detail).

Answer (score 0):

$this->hasOne(testModel::class, ['telephone_id' => 'id']);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Do not have any experience with Laravel, but based on your question I assume Lavarel will return empty array() in your example?

Yii2 will always return null if no relation rows were found, except for scalar relations. Common Yii2 way to check if model has related items:

```
if($model->posts !== null) {
    foreach($model->posts as $post) {
       /* Do something with the $post */
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use scalar relation, something like:

```
public function getPostsCount() {
    return $this->hasMany(Posts::class, ['author' => 'id'])->count();
} // $model->postsCount will return count of user posts, 0 in case user does not have any posts
```

To me it would make more sense if $model->posts would return empty array() instead of null, with apparent benefit that !== null statement would not be required each time. However, I guess this is something you get used to while developing on Yii2.